# Laravel relationship hasmany query seems to be wrong

Tags: orm, laravel

I'm trying eloquent relationship for the first time and I'm scratching my head for hours around this problem...here my code:

Rides model

```
 public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Messages', 'ride_id');
}
```

Messages model

```
class Messages extends Eloquent {

 protected $guarded = ['id']; 

 public function message(){

    return $this->belongsTo('Rides');

 }

}
```

Rides controller

```
        public function show($user)
        {

         $ride = Rides::with('user')->where('id' ,'=',$user->id)->get();

         $ridesObj = new Rides();

         $messages =   $ridesObj->messages()->where('ride_id', '=',$ride[0]->id)->get();

         return View::make('site/rides/show')     
         ->with('ride',$ride)
         ->with('messages',$messages);     

        }
```

The $messages collection is always empty, by looking the query:
    select * from `messages` where `messages`.`ride_id` is null and `ride_id` = '5'
the problem is  where `messages`.`ride_id` is null 
Why and how that condition is created?

Comment: In your `$ridesObj->messages()->where('ride_id', '=',$ride[0]->id)...` the `where()` statement is redundant. The `$ride->message` is already implicitly limiting the messages returned to messages associated with the Ride.

I recommend checking out the Eloquent docs and experimenting with ` `php artisan tinker` a bit

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Rides object, and querying the messages for that "new" Rides object, which none exist because its a new object.  You need to query for messages on the original $ride object.

```
// change method from "get" to "first" since you're only interested in the first ride
$ride = Rides::with('user')->where('id' ,'=',$user->id)->first();


$messages = $ride->messages;
```

That should do what you expected above I believe.  The main concept is that the messages belong to the ride object you searched for.  When you create a new Rides object, it doesn't have any messages attached to it yet because its a new instantiation all together.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications/simplifications to your snippet(s) below.

This is not tested, but should work assuming that your hasMany() and belongsTo() are functioning to begin with.

I recommend testing `echo Rides::find($user->id)->messages;` and `echo Rides::find($user->id)->user;` in `php artisan tinker`

```
public function show($user)
{

    /**
     * Utilize ORM in the view ($ride->messages and $ride->user). Eager loading may come in handy for many to many relationship... not necessarily needed for what you are doing here.
     */
    $ride = Rides::find($user->id);
    // DEPRECATED $ride     = Rides::with('user', 'messages')->find($user->id);

    return View::make('site/rides/show')     
         ->with('ride',$ride);
}
```

Inside of your view rides/show, you should be able to do something like

```
<ul>
    @foreach($ride->messages as $message)
        <li>{{$message->title}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

[Eloquent Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

Find me on twitter: @ErikOnTheWeb

Comment: Actually... since the n+1 problem really doesn't apply to the messages, you are probably better off simplifying down to something like... Controller: `$ride     = Rides::find($user->id);` View: `foreach($ride->messages as $message)` and `$ride->user` ... I could be wrong, but I believe that would be just as efficient, query-wise and save you some code/complication